# Value types in java

Tags: java, return-value

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    int x = 5;
    addOneTo(x);
    System.out.println(x);       
}

static int addOneTo(int num) {
    return  num + 1;
}
```

}

I expected it to return 6!!
But it do return 5

Why

Comment: Java is 'pass by value' -- nothing you do to a parameter affects the variable which was used by the caller as a parameter. You are discarding the return value of addToOne.

Answer (score 0):

You have just added 1 to the int variable and returning it and you didnt assign it back to int variable in main method.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    int x = 5;
    System.out.println(addOneTo(x));       
}

static int addOneTo(int num) {
    return  num + 1;
}
```